# In Angular 4, how do I target an auxiliary outlet with a child route?

Tags: angular

https://plnkr.co/edit/TXo6Ua

The above linked Plunker demonstrates the problem I am having.  I want to have an auxiliary router that can be used to show modal windows such as Login or Logout modal.  I am using child routes to allow for routing to be defined in functional modules (only one module in the plunker).  Here are the routes I have defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'detail', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'modal' },
  { 
    path: 'heros', 
    children: [
      { path: 'display', component: HeroDisplayComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: HeroCreateComponent, outlet: 'modal' }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'heroCreate', component: HeroCreateComponent, outlet: 'modal' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } 
]
```

And here are the links I am trying to use to bring up the various parts of my application:

```
<ul>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a> - Display a welcome message in the unnamed router-outlet</li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['heros/display']">Hero Display</a> - Display a Hero Display Page in the unnamed router-outlet</li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'modal': 'heroCreate'}}]">Hero Create Normal</a> - Display a Hero Create Page in the "modal" router-outlet Through a non-child route</li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'modal': 'heros/create'}}]">Hero Create Child</a> - Should display a "Hero Create" section in the "modal" router-outlet</li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'modal': 'detail' }}]">Detail</a> - Should display a "Detail" secion in the "modal" router-outlet</li>
</ul>
```

All the links above work as expected except the "Hero Create Child" link.  This one gets the following error:

```
errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'heros/create'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'heros/create'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (apply_redirects.ts:117)
at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (apply_redirects.ts:102)
at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.ts:105)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (apply_redirects.ts:117)
at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (apply_redirects.ts:102)
at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.ts:105)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.ts:109)
at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.ts:139)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:754)
at zone.js:831
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:288)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
at ____________________Elapsed_1_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_49_00_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:778)
at ____________________Elapsed_0_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_49_00_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:778)
at ____________________Elapsed_0_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_49_00_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:778)
at ____________________Elapsed_2_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_49_00_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at ZoneAwarePromise.then (zone.js:918)
at ____________________Elapsed_3_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_49_00_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at ZoneAwarePromise.then (zone.js:918)
at ____________________Elapsed_5048_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_48_55_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleEventTask (zone.js:261)
at HTMLAnchorElement.addEventListener (zone.js:1640)
at DomEventsPlugin.addEventListener (dom_events.ts:37)
at ____________________Elapsed_12_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_48_55_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:778)
at ____________________Elapsed_0_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_48_55_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:778)
at ____________________Elapsed_0_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_48_55_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:778)
at ____________________Elapsed_0_ms__At__Sun_Aug_13_2017_11_48_55_GMT_0400__EDT_ (localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (long-stack-trace-zone.js:109)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:300)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
at Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:235)
at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone.js:255)
at scheduleResolveOrReject (zone.js:829)
at ZoneAwarePromise.then (zone.js:918)
```

I have been banging my head against this all weekend, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your modal outlet located? In a root component?

Comment: @LyubimovRoman yes, it is in the root component.

Comment: Not sure but I guess it works with one routes level only. Why not to use a modal library? Instead of making umconvinient solution. E.g. ng-bootstrap

Comment: The answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741936/angular-4-multiple-named-router-outlets-in-a-child-route-supported?rq=1 got me a step further.

I changed my "Hero Create Child" link to:
    <li><a [routerLink]="['heros',{outlets: {'modal': 'create'}}]">Hero Create Child</a> - Should display a "Hero Create" section in the "modal" router-outlet</li>

But now, if I click on another link that targets the 'modal' outlet, I end up with a messed up URL: "/heros/(display//modal:create)(modal:detail)"

Answer (score 0):

I think this post answers to your question:
http://blog.obyte.it/news/js/add-generic-modal-in-angular-app/

A brief explanation below.
You can add a named router-outlet:

```
<router-outlet name="modal" id="container-modal"> </router-outlet>
```

and call it in the router through the "outlet" property:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
     path: 'modal-item-1',
     component: ModalItemOneComponent,
     outlet: 'modal'
   }, {
     path: 'modal-item-2',
     component: ModalItemTwoComponent,
     outlet: 'modal'
   }
];
```

Inside it you can insert the components you want.