# Angular 2/4: Use two router outlets simultaneously side-by-side

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46103912) suggests how I can put components into two separate router-outlets based on the route. But components cannot communicate to each other (unless separate service is used).

So I wonder if it is possible to output components, based on route AND still have an easy communication between components via Inputs and Outputs?

**Important:** components go side-by-side, it is not a child component within a parent component.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4: Multiple (named) router-outlets in a child route: supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741936/angular-4-multiple-named-router-outlets-in-a-child-route-supported)

Comment: @msanford, I suppose it is different in the way components communicate.

Comment: I think that in this case the best approach is to use either a shared service (that exposes an observable, receives a new value an then emits an update) or a state container (for example, what Redux does).