# Two Router Angular5 not works

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular5

**principal.component.html**

```
[...]
<a routerLink="/empresa-list">Abrir</a>
[...]
<main>
<router-outlet name="content"><router-outlet>
</main>
[...]
```

**app.compoment.html**

```
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

const ROUTES:Routes =[

    {path:'principal', loadChildren: 'app/principal/principal.module#PrincipalModule'}
]

@NgModule({
    imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

**principal.routing.module.ts**

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { PrincipalComponent } from "./principal.component";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { EmpresaListasComponent } from "../empresa/empresa-listas/empresa-listas.component";

const PRINCIPAL_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: PrincipalComponent},
    {path: 'empresa-list', component:EmpresaListasComponent, outlet: 'content'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports:[RouterModule.forChild(PRINCIPAL_ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PrincipalRoutingModule{}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,                 
    PrincipalModule,
    AppRoutingModule,   

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**principal.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
declarations:[
    PrincipalComponent
],
 imports:[
    MaterializeModule,
    PrincipalRoutingModule,
    EmpresaModule

 ],
 exports:[PrincipalComponent]
})
export class PrincipalModule{}
```

Now let's get into my problem.
When I click on the `empresa-list` router, I get the following error in the console

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can not match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'empresa-list' Error: Can not match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'empresa-list'

I've tried many things to make it work, so far unsuccessful.
What I want is for the ComponentListComponent component to be rendered inside the `main` tag of my `PrincipalComponent`.
Every help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand it correct. If you want to display  EmpresaListasComponent  in PrincipalComponent then you should make it child route. Did you try this?

```
const PRINCIPAL_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: PrincipalComponent,
      children: [
        {path: 'empresa-list', component:EmpresaListasComponent, outlet:'content'}
    ]
},
];
```

Comment: i will try, one moment

Comment: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'empresa-list'
This a error

Comment: I did, I just had to remove the router's outlet parameter and the name attribute of the <router-outlet>

Comment: `{path: '', component: PrincipalComponent, 
    children:[
        {path: 'empresa-list', component:EmpresaListasComponent}
    ]},`

and inside `main` `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Yes , I was typing this actually :). if u want to use named router , you should use it like in this link.    [routerLink]="['/stuff',{outlets:{editsection:':index/edit'}}]">Edit</button>   
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741936/angular-4-multiple-named-router-outlets-in-a-child-route-supported/44742481