# Displaying a view on the same page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I want to display a view on the same page in an Angular application when the button is clicked.

The page should not open in a new page, instead it should be displayed in the same page, below the existing page elements.

How can I do that in Angular using routing?

Here is an illustration of what I want:

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741936/angular-4-multiple-named-router-outlets-in-a-child-route-supported

Comment: You can have your view2 already created and show it on click, or you can create it dynamically. I don't entirely see how you want to do it by routing, can you give us more information of how you want to do it?

Comment: I want to do it by routing because I want to also change the URL of the page also while also keeping the view in the same page only.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a child route where in you would define a component. In your parent component / route, declare a router-outlet tag.

Whenever, you navigate to the child route/URL, the child component would fit into the router-outlet tag of its parent.

You may explore more here - https://alligator.io/angular/angular-router-child-routes/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ngIf on selector of second component

```
<button  (click)="changeBoolean()">

    <selector-second-component *ngIf="showComponent">  <selector-second-component>
```

On button click you will set boolean to true to show that component.

**.ts first component**

```
changeBoolean()
{
    this.showComponent = true;
}
```

If your component is from other module you will have to import that module and export your component from that module.

Comment: I need to that when the user clicks on the button.

Comment: it was understood that you need to change boolean on button click

Answer (score 0):

Following Ankit Sharma's provided [link](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-router-child-routes/). Here's what you need to do.

> Define child routes is to add an array of additional route
>   configuration objects as part of a children key in your parent
>   configuration

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ParentComponent, children: [
    { path: 'view-one', component: ViewOneComponent },
    { path: 'view-two', component: ViewTwoComponent }
  ] }
];
```

And, make sure you are adding `router-outlet` directive in the template of any parent component.

```js
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```